# Help with these calculations in Conway's complex analysis book

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm studying [Conway's complex analysis book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387903283) and on page 9 he gets this relation between the point $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ in the [Riemann sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere) and $z$ in the extended plane $\mathbb C_{\infty}$:

[image]

Afterwards, he said that these calculations in 6.3 gives us the following expressions for the distance:

[image]

I've tried a lot to prove the equation above without success. Is there a trick or a hint to simplify these calculations?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean just 6.8, or both 6.7 and 6.8?

Comment: For 6.8, is it enough just to consider $\lim_{w\to 0} d(z,\frac1w)$?

Comment: @MPW Any help is welcome. For 6.8 I think is solved directly from 6.7.